# Invalid Magic Number on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, grub2

I have received the following error after rebooting my virtual machine:

```
Error: Invalid magic number.
alloc magic is broken as 0x7e92a4a0: 7e845c0
Aborted. Press any key to exit.
```

I have scoured the internet to no avail.